# Electron: what's the semantics of require('electron')?

Tags: javascript, electron

I working on an Electron app and am wrangling badly trying to understand how to access files from the scripts running in my renderer.  So I am trying to share the filesystem path, which main.js knows, with the scripts which render the UI.

I used this example as a guideline:

https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/helloworld-sharedobj

I can get it to work just fine as the example is written.  However, index.html isn't where I need the path, but rather the in the scripts that render the UI, which are in a ~/js folder.

However, if I move the code to a script, I get an error when I try to `var remote = require('electron').remote;` that it "Cannot resolve module 'electron"

I solved it, horribly, by leaving the code in index.html and making "remote" a global variable.  That can't be the right way to do it.

What do I need to do in order to access the 'electron' module in my JavaScript code?
`

Comment: Basically you just want to separate your .html and you front-end rendering library right ?

Comment: I'm trying to grok how to get the absolute paths so they can be used with file:// to bring in assets (e.g. img and css).  I.e. in the renderer process which is where the above-mentioned require fails; it works fine in main.js but not in my service scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack(recent version) as a module bundler, you can set the development target in the renderer configuration.

```
module.exports = {
 target: 'electron-renderer',
}
```

If you are not using webpack in your project, then you can try the below code.

```
var remote = window.require('electron').remote;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem, but I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
// index.html
<script>
  require('path/to/my-js-file');
</script>

// my-js-file.js
var remote = require('electron').remote;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to maintain a single tree for a SPA which is both a webapp (where relative paths are cool) and--for want of a better word--a file://-app (where relative paths do not seem to be cool) to be run with Electron.

In other words, in the main.js file I can post a new renderer window to open up ~/public/index.html, but I struggle to find a way to open up img and css files kept as relative paths (to /public) in my .js files.

The fix so far was to use the electron-window convenience methods

https://github.com/jprichardson/electron-window

Following the example there I pick up the absolute path as shown and now my scripts can fulfill their needs.